# Capybara tests - alternative to sleep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I’ve been trying to find alternatives to using sleep for some time and it seems that every single suggested method to avoid using sleep never works and I’m at the end of my rope.

```
it 'finds the correct product when searching by job type', js: true do
    fill_in('filterrific_for_work_type', with: 'Central')
    # once again, sleep feels like the only thing that works
    #sleep 1 # TODO: find a better way..
    expect(find('#work_queue_items_filter_reset')).to have_content('Reset All Filters')
    expect(page).to have_link('IP Central Report',
                              href: work_queue_item_path(@release.id))
  end
```

I also have this wait for ajax helper:

```
module CapybaraHelpers
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end
```

And in spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include CapybaraHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

This test breaks unless I add the sleep 1.  and I’ve tried so many iterations using things like ‘within’ ‘find’, ‘have_content’ ect.  This is really driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

As long as there are visible changes being made on a page wait_for_ajax should almost never be needed.  You don't say exactly what error you are getting, but the way I would write your expectation would be

```
expect(page).to have_css('#work_queue_items_filter_reset', text: 'Reset All Filters')
```

if that doesn't work then it may just be that you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time set too short for the hardware/app you're testing.  You can test that by specifying a custom wait time in your expectation to see if it makes a difference

```
expect(page).to have_css('#work_queue_items_filter_reset', text: 'Reset All Filters', wait: 10) # wait up to 10 seconds for matching element to appear
```

Comment: I don't get it  - I have Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10.  I tried both of those have_css options you suggested and it failed.   When I add sleep 1, the test passes!!   WTF?

Comment: @user1200990 What driver are you using? What error exactly do you get? How does your page function? ie - what triggers the page to do anything when the field is filled in.

Comment: @user1200990 Also what ruby are you running your tests on?

Comment: @TomWalpole I deleted my answer, I just checked this and I must have not been using the correct syntax for `have_link` without text.

Comment: @RobWise  You probably didn't pass the required first parameter nil when not checking text - the need for it will be going away in the next capybara release (was planned to be gone in 2.9 but I forgot about it) - it is gone in Capybaras master branch.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply - was out the last 3 days.   I'm using Poltergeist for my driver.   The error I'm getting is that, without sleep, the expect(page).to have_link('IP Central Report',
                              href: work_queue_item_path(@release.id)) finder throws an exception.   The trigger for the field is a jquery input change listener:   $('#filterrific_filter').on(
    "change",
    ":input",
    Filterrific.submitFilterForm
  );

Comment: @user1200990  So the have_content matcher is working correctly, but the have_link is failing for you?  Add the exact error message you're getting from the have_link matcher to your question, along with details on what \@release is and how it's created.

Comment: I'm using ruby -v = 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You should never use "sleep" with Capybara. The methods like
https://github.com/ordinaryzelig/capybara_minitest_spec

they use sleep inside them.

Comment: I know I should never use sleep.   I'm using rspec and Capybara for this test suite and I feel like I've exhausted every don't-use-sleep technique out there and I still can't seem to get anything but sleep to work.

Comment: This test is testing for the correct filtering of a collection of database associations.   The strange thing is that, with sleep, the collection is able to be displayed and the individual rows are able to display their proper db associations.   For instance, on this line in the view: [code]<%=link_to(wqi.workable.getType, work_queue_item_path(wqi)) %>[/code], the wqi.workable is not nil.  Without sleep the wqi.workable is nil so it's a race condition between Capybara testing for elements and the collection fully having time to process it's dependencies.